# Socket IO not found (404)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am having some trouble getting socket io to work beyond the example from their tutorial.

The problem is when I want to call the `chatDiv.html` from a website on my local apache server.

I have my node js server called `index.js`

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {

// Website you wish to allow to connect
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
// to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Pass to next layer of middleware
next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/chatDiv.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
    console.log(msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
```

client file loaded by  the server is `chatDiv.html`

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<div class="chat body">
<ul style="width:100%;height:100px;" id="messages"></ul>

<input style="width:100px;height:20px"id="m" autocomplete="off">  </input><button id="sendM"   >Send</button>
    
</div>
```

Finally, I want to interact with socket io from my apache server. I do this by loading the contents of `chatDiv.html` into a container like so

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#chatContainer").load("http://localhost:3000/", function() {
    console.log('loaded chatdiv');
    var socket = io();
    $( "#chatContainer" ).on( "click", "#sendM", function() {
      console.log('clicked');
    }); 
  }); 
});
```

Now the contents of chatDiv are being loaded to my website and I can see a socket io file being loaded. But it is getting an error when calling
var socket = io();

```
GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=L8zL8x0 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you be specific on what error you are having? You might want to wrap a try-catch block around your io() to see if it gives you any hint. I suspect it has something to do with your port access privilege or firewall settings.

example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#chatContainer").load("http://localhost:3000/", function() {
        console.log('loaded chatdiv');
        try{
           var socket = io();
        }
        catch(e){
           //log the error here
           console.log(e);
        }
        $( "#chatContainer" ).on( "click", "#sendM", function() {
            console.log('clicked');
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: the error was GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=L8zL8x0 404 (Not Found)

or do you need it to be more specific?